# SSIS - Adding date from filename in the date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, ssis

I have a flat file that I am importing into a SQL Server table using SSIS. I'd like to know if we can extract the date from file name and add it to a column in SQL Server from the SRC SSIS package?

I know  can do this via derived columns but would really like to know specifics on how do I start doing this?

Comment: If you know about derived column, what else you do you need to know?

Comment: I created a derived column but what do I add in expressions? and how do I tell SSIS to extract date from the filename and add it to the SQL table?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you know the filename, So you need to define a Variable (call it DtFromName) and extract DATE from filename and put it the variable (you can use Script Task to do that).

Then you can use that variable in your Derived Column. See following images, Hope you can get the solution.

Your package looks like this. Note the variables on left side

[image: Variables and Package Items]

Now double-click on Script Task and assign the variables to ReadOnly and ReadWrite

[image: Variable and your Data Flow]

Now, click on "Edit Script" button to open VS IDE and write some code to extract date from your FileName variable and store it into DtFromName variable.

Something like this

[image]

In Data Flow control, you'll have something like this:

[image]

Now, double click on Derived Column and in expression of Derived Column, use that variable ad the Derived Column

[image]

Now you have the date string in Derived Column. You should be able to take over the rest.

Comment: what kind of Script Task is it? I am not sure how to extract the date

Comment: Do you know how to use Script Task?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to run the package now but instead of writing a Script task to edit the filename and extract date from filename, I used the following logic in expressions: SUBSTRING(DateClean,5,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING(DateClean,7,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING(DateClean,1,4)

Comment: do I have to map the column name in the destination task? the code runs but I cant see the column in table @FLICKER

Comment: Yes, after derived field object, you'll have the field as an extra filed and you need to map it at destination